# Total number of Review count in Recent Review link on Review Page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, review-queues, technical

Total number of `reviews count in week` are shown a wrong on the Review page while mousing over a Person's Icon/Image.

See red circles in below screenshots.

Per person 20 reviews are allowed per day (sometimes moderators are able to do more than 20 reviews in a day but I am not able to do so, so in my case I only review 20 per day), then while mousing over my icon in the `recent reviews` link, it shows 160 reviews in a week.

I think that's not possible (week has 7 days and per day 20 reviews), so no more than 140 can be in a week.

[image]

**EDIT**:- Recent screenshot for Close Votes Queue

[image]

Comment: If a review queue has over a 1000 items, you get 40 reviews per day - so it is possible. But with the Reopen queue that is probably not the reason.

Comment: Only for Close Votes, we get 40 reviews per day, but I get this for Reopen/First Posts queue.

Comment: We get it in the Close Votes queue because it has more than 1000 items. But indeed, for Reopen and First Posts, there must be another reason why this happens.

Comment: @ S.L. Barth:- I add new Screenshot for Close votes where its shows 320/per week. I think 40 reviwes per day, for 7 days become not more than 280 per week

Comment: It looks as if in the "week" one, it's calculating for 8 days instead of 7. If you do the math on your close vote screenshot, it is exactly 40 over what it should be (280) for 7 days at 40 reviews/day. That might very well be what is causing the issue, is an extra day in the count.

Comment: @Kendra:- may be wrong calculation for week or some other logic

Comment: @Kendra I'm guessing it uses "past week + today". Either deliberately or through an off-by-one error in the Stack Exchange code.

Comment: @S.L. Barth:- if it is shows "past week + today" data, then it means already new week started, and week data beome itself wrong

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's about what I was starting to think. It makes sense, and explains the issue. It just then becomes a question of "If this is deliberate, why?" If it's not, I'm sure someone will find it and fix it at some point.