# How can a user have more Late reviews than the current limit?

Tags: bug, review-queues, rate-limiting, late-answers

I have noticed that a user reviewed 338 Late Answers this month:

---

[image]

According to [the most recent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/3982001) I've found about limits,

> - When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day
> - When the queue size is less than 150, you will have 20 reviews a day

Since the Late Answers queue is certainly always below 150, and considering today is the 9th, he should have at most 9*20=180 reviews. It would be ok if the limit was 40, but I am active in that queue and I'm sure I've never seen anyone with more than 20 reviews in it (except for that experiment in March). Everybody stops at 20 every day.

There's a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290354/total-number-of-review-count-in-recent-review-link-on-review-page) with comments suggesting that the stats count one extra day for a week. Maybe, but I'm talking about the month now, which is not over, so I don't think it applies.

An [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332283/3982001) to another question says "the numbers on the \review page are heavily cached". But I don't think this can be due to caching; even updating the cache only once a week would solve the problem.

So, why is that number so high? It might be something harmless (that is, the number I've seen is wrong, but the system works correctly, stopping at 20 every day), or there might be a bug that lets someone go beyond that limit. I think the most likely explanation is the first one. Maybe that number also includes reviews from other queues? Or from the previous month?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the context of review stats, the counts do not reset at the beginning of each week and month. The week accounts for the past 7 days, and the month accounts for the past 30 days. The user has reviewed 338 items in the past 30 days, not the past 9 days.